# Reasons for losing reputation

Tags: support, reputation, rules

Today, my SO reputation decreased by around 160 points. I know that reputation is lost in following cases

- Answer to a question which gets closed and ultimately deleted.
- If the answer to any question is deleted by me (then rep will be lost during cleanup).

AFAIK I had answered to a question which was closed soon, and may be deleted recently. But, 160 rep is definitely not due to it.

Are there any more reasons as to why my rep got missing and how do I know that lost rep is actually due to system cleanup and be quiet?

Thanks.

Comment: what happens to "feature-request" questions? Should I un-accept the now accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You requested a rep-recalc. The results aren't always additive. You were emailed about this a little over an hour ago after your request was made.

Comment: Did he really not remember that?

Comment: Yes. I got the mail. Checked it now. I am fine with the rep lost :) actually, but I *do* want to know what action (as in which question) caused this.

Comment: @Down: I know I flagged for rep re-calc :D. But, since I didn't check my mail, I wasn't sure if it was recalc by moderator or _some unicorn_ :).

Comment: @nvl Unfortunately I'm not sure if we're able to say specifically which questions/answers caused the changes in rep.

Comment: @nvl a rep loss on a recalc can have any number of reasons, e.g. answers you gave to questions that were deleted later, that received upvotes, a question you deleted etc. etc.

Comment: Can't there be an automated system detailing what caused the rep change (plus/minus) and sent as email to user. That would at least reduce the number of rep questions on Meta :)

Comment: @nvl `[feature-request]`'s are always welcomed :)

Comment: @Pekka: I have mentioned those reasons in OP, but IMO they don't seem to be the reason for 160 reps.

Comment: @nvl I think they must be - you have no "spam" flags (that would cost you 100) and very few downvotes.... Your feature request is surely a good idea.

Comment: @Pekka: may be they are the reason for -160, but a mail about the changes would be better for all. :)